# JAVASCRIPT NATIVE get Запрос с базовой авторизацией

Tags: javascript, fetch, xmlhttprequest

пытаюсь отправить get запрос к базе данных, там нужно пройти basic auth , ввожу данные через header

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('key:key2'))
```

запрос не проходит. Через PostMan всё работает, я даже копировал оттуда basic header , но через Js никак не отправляется запрос с авторизацией

код:

```
xhr.open("GET", 'https://site//wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses/')
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('key:key2'))
xhr.send(null)
```

Comment: Ошибки выходят
401 UNAUTHORIZED

Comment: XHROPTIONS site//wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses CORS Preflight Did Not Succeed